# Query with LIKE, increasingly slow with a smaller resultset

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-like

Say I have a Person table with 200000 records, there's a clustered index on it's GUID primary key. This GUID is generated using the NEWSEQUENTIALID() construct provided by SQL Server (2008 R2). Furthermore there is a regular index on the LastName (varchar(256)) column.

For every record I've generated a unique name (Lastname_1 through Lastname_200000), now I'm playing around with some queries and have come to find that the more restrictive my criteria is, the slower SQL Server will return actual results. And this performance implication is quite severe.

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Lastname LIKE '%Lastname_123456%'
```

Is much slower than

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Lastname LIKE '%Lastname_123%'
```

Responsetimes are measured by setting statistics on:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

I can imagine this being caused

1) Because of the LIKE clause itself, since it starts with % it isn't possible to use the inde on that particular column,

2) SQL having to think more about my 'bigger question'.

Is there any truth in this? Is there some way to avoid this?

Edit:
To add some context to this question, this is part of a use case for a 'free search'. I would very much like the system to be fast when a user enters a full lastname.

How should I make these cases perform? Should I avoid the '%xxx%' construction and go for 'xxx%' like construction? Which does add alot of speed, but at the cost of some flexibility for the user...

Comment: Please show the execution plans. Maybe different selectivity estimates meaning one does a clustered index scan and the other an NCI scan and key lookups.

Comment: Did you generate all your names sequentially?

Comment: As in Many DBs, yes. A prefix or Suffixed like can use indexes but not that kind of one since the DB just does not know the range and cannot apply it to an index. Also that is a rather long string so it does put pressure on there too

Comment: @martin, the execution plans look pretty much the same. When I issue the search with just 'Lastname_', a clustered index  scan is executed, which is quite fast. When I change it to something like 'Lastname_123', an index scan (52%) and key lookup (42%) is performed>

DavidBrabant: Aye, Lastname_1 through Lastname_200000

Comment: @fuaaark - What is the complete output of `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` including CPU time?

Comment: The optimiser has determined (perhaps wrongly) that a bookmark lookup is the best way to return the desired results for the first query, but not the second (I don't understand the optimiser well enough to know how it determines this, hence a comment and not an answer). If you alter your nonclustered index on last name to `INCLUDE` the columns you want to return in the select list the optimiser will not need to do the bookmark lookup.

Comment: @fuaaark - I'm confused. You say they look the same but then describe two different plans. Are you talking about different queries for these?

Comment: @martin, Sorry for the mix up, the query plans generated for 'Lastname_123' and 'Lastname_123456' are basically the same. 

I also took a look at the query plan generated for 'Lastname_', and that only issues a clustered index scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on with number 2, since the second LIKE must match more characters in the string, SQL stops searching when it finds a character that doesn't match so it takes less string matching iterations to find a smaller search string - even though you get more results back.

As for #1 - SQL will use an index if possible for a LIKE, but will probably do an index scan (probably the clustered index) since a seek is not possible with a wildcard. It also depends on what's included in the index - since you are selecting all columns, it's likely that a table scan is happening instead since the index you 'could' use is not covering your query (unless it's using the clustered index)

Check your execution plan - you will likely see a table scan

Answer (score 0):

Usually, SQL Server does not use indexes on a LIKE.

[This](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx) article can help guide you

Comment: True but doesn't answer the question asked which is about the performance of two specific queries.